# Como resolver advertencia CA1063 sobre la correcta implementación de IDisposable

Tags: c#, interop

Actualmente estoy intentando eliminar todas las advertencias, y me ha causado muchos problemas la CA1063.

He leído bastante documentación Microsoft, sobre los patrones de diseño de IDisposble, pero sigo sin poder implementarla correctamente.

Las dos adevtencias que me aparecen son la siguientes: Elimine el finalizador del tipo `MiClase`, anule `Dispose (bool disposing)` y coloque la lógica de finalización en la ruta de código donde `disposing` es falso y la otra es Modifique `MiClase.Finalize ()` para que llame a `Dispose (false)` y luego regrese.

Lo que yo hice fue eliminar la lógica del `Finalizer` y llamar `Dispose(false)`, mientras que intenté implementar el método `Dispose(bool disposing)`, me indicaba un error, ya que este método ya estaba creado como override en el diseñador.
Por lo que decidí crear una condición en el diseñador para cuando `disposing` fuera falso y ahí agregué la lógica de mi `Finalizer`. No obstante, solamente desapareció la primera advertencia.

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

**MiClase.cs**

```
~MiClase()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

**MiClase.Diseñador.cs**

```
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
    
        try
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        if (!disposing)
        {
            try
            {
                this.bindingRPM_SinkMode = null;
                this.numericAvfaderRPM_SinkMode = null;
                this.bindingSPEED_SinkMode = null;
                this.numericAvfaderSPEED_SinkMode = null;
                this.bindingLOAD_SinkMode = null;
                this.numericAvfaderLOAD_SinkMode = null;

                if (this.AVFaderRPM != null)
                    this.AVFaderRPM.Dispose();
                if (this.AVFaderSpeed != null)
                    this.AVFaderSpeed.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in " + this.GetType().Name + ".cs: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "(): " + ex.Message);
                this.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: podrías colocar la clase 'MiClase.cs' completa con declaraciones e imports ? Te quiero ayudar

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1063?view=vs-2019 hablamos de esta regla no?